# How make my screen goes up together with keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout

How I get notified when the keyboard is going up?

I has a FrameLayout and it doesn't get resized when it's goes up, so I need to translate the screen myself.

This is my actual layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">
<br.view.image.ScrollableImage
    android:id="@+id/image01" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<br.view.TopBarView android:id="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<br.view.BottomBarView
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

From inside the BottomBar I open a PopupWindow wich a EditText and a Button.

When touch the EditText, the soft keyboard just overlay the bottom of the screen covering even the popup window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this SO question [Android: which event fires when on screen keyboard appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268820/android-which-event-fires-when-on-screen-keyboard-appears)